# CSS vh unit on touch devices Issue

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css

Is there a way, to prevent the resize behaviour on touch devices?
My problem is that *what if*  I have a section which height is `60vh`. This section is at the top of the page. When the user start scrolling, the address bar is disappearing from the window, and the browser is refreshing the `vh` unit (If i'm correct).

**index.html**

```
<section class="top-section">
 <!-- lots of code here -->
</section>
```

**style.css**

```
.top-section {
  height:60vh;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this in CSS, or there is no other way and use Javascript for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are speaking about creating your top bar ( with navigation buttons and stuff), most correct way to hide fixed element would be to use JS.

You have two options:

option 1) have relative top bar. and it will hide when you scroll
option 2) have it fixed, but use a listener (scrollTop()) to decide when to open/close the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

i made an example for you. the vh value is not changing if you add/remove items. it will only change on screen resize not on document resize. see snippet below ( the height of topsection will appear on scroll as text inside the section, and it's not changing ) or [jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38f1aru6/4/)

```js
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
    $(".address-bar").hide()
   }else{
    $(".address-bar").show()
   }
 $(".top-section").text($(this).height())

});
```

```css
.address-bar {
 height:5vh;
 background:blue;
}
.top-section {
 height:60vh;
 background:red;
}
.content-section {
 height:100vh;
 background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="address-bar">
 
</section>
<section class="top-section">

</section>
<section class="content-section">

</section>
```